# android layout center and bottom

Tags: android

In my layout i want to display two imagebuttons in the center and a my amountmeter below it on the bottom, all centered vertically, i have tried many ways but cant seem to find that perfect layout. all the component align vertically and center but it makes my amountmeter small and not full width of the screen.

How it should be

[image: how it should be]

how it is now

[image: how it is now]

updated code
current layout:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/purchase"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_cart" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/sell"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/round_button"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_sell" />

<com.example.mobile.view.AmountMeterView
    android:id="@+id/mobileAmount"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center|bottom"
    android:padding="4dp" />
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

COPY PASTE BELOW CODE

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/purchase"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/sell"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/purchase"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <com.example.mobile.view.AmountMeterView
        android:id="@+id/mobileAmount"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/sell"
        android:padding="4dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

AFTER THAT

```
  android:background="@drawable/round_button"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_sell"

android:background="@drawable/round_button"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_cart"
```

PUT THIS LINE TO YOUR TWO IMAGE BUTTONS SURELY IT WILL WORK FOR YOU

Comment: hi, thanks for the reply, works great, amountmeter still not displaying full width of screen but its oky, im just going to keep it the way you mentioned thanks.

Comment: will do, thanks for the reply, one last question if i may, how would one adjust the size of the component that is aligned to the bottom? ie amountview in question. can a width be set using dip? how will it react on different screen sizes?

Comment: normaly setting width by static value is bad programming cause in android there are various screen sizes and to give mulitple screen support then such kind of issue will come

so its good to give height and width through gravity and through weight

Answer (score 0):

One Linear layout is enough for this. Do not put your `AmountMeterView` into it's own LinearLayout.

Just make one Linear layout (vertical), and put all three elements in there. Gravity center_horizontal for all elements.

Comment: if you need more help, just feel free to ask.

Comment: changed it, still displays everything aligned etc 100%, but my amountmeter is still cropped and not displayed the full width of the screen, even with layout_width set to fill_parent.

Answer (score 0):

Try in this way hope this will help you

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/purchase"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/sell"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/round_button"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="2"

        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <com.example.mobile.view.AmountMeterView
            android:id="@+id/mobileAmount"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="4dp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: hi, thank for the reply,using this code i got the following: http://i.imgur.com/vK33CK4.jpg

Comment: ok give android:layout_weight="1" to your <com.vasx.mobile.view.AmountMeterView>

Comment: no change in the layout if add a weight of 1 to the amountmeter

Comment: i got the solution you have to set android:gravity="center" in your AmountMeterView